# Print all combinations when input is String vs List<String> in Java

Tags: java, algorithm

Popular problem: print all combinations of input.

Both the first code block and 2nd code block have the same structures. I did debug and track stack, but couldn't understand. That's why I'm posting.

If input is List, the following code works and I understand it.
remain should be backtracked.

```
  ex: input list = ["a", "b", "c"]
  public void sublists(List<String> list) {  
    List<String> chosen = new ArrayList<>();
    sublists(chosen, list);
  }

  private void sublists(List<String> chosen, List<String> remain) {
    if(remain.size() == 0) {
      System.out.println(chosen);
    }
    else {
      String first = remain.remove(0);

      // choose/explore INC. first
      chosen.add(first);
      sublists(chosen, remain);

      // choose/explore EXC first
      chosen.remove(chosen.size() -1);
      sublists(chosen, remain);

      // un-choose for backtracking
      remain.add(first);
    }
  }
```

However, the same question but different input type, when input is String, doesn't need backtracking of remain in the code below.

Q1: why `remain += C;` is not reachable in code block below while   `remain.add(first);` is reachable in the code block above even though these two code blocks have the same code structure? In both code block, recursion method get called recursively.

Q2: `remain += C;` not even needed since it's automatically backed its removed char. Why?

```
  // ex: input s = "abc"

  public void combination2(String s) {
    combination2Helper("", s);
  }

  private void combination2Helper(String chosen, String remain) {
    if (remain.length() == 0) {
      System.out.println(chosen);
    }
    else {
      char C = remain.charAt(0);
      chosen += C;
      remain = remain.substring(1);

      // inc. C + remain w/o C
      combination2Helper(chosen, remain);

      // exc. C + remain w/o C
      chosen = chosen.substring(0, chosen.length() -1 );
      combination2Helper(chosen, remain);

      // why this backtrack of ramin is not reachable unlike when remain is list 
      // backtrackig this line is not needed.
      remain += C;
    }
```

Besides if the input is string, we don't even need such a long line of code right above.
The following code is working.

Q3: Theoretically we need to backtrack what we've chosen after the recursion call for exhaustive search but why this code doesn't need backtracking of chosen nor remain when the input type is String? 
When the input is List, if don't use backtracking, it doesn't work.

I'm confused why the backtracking is not reachable ( not needed ) when input is String while List is needed.

```
  private void combination2Helper(String chosen, String remain) {
    if (remain.length() == 0) {
      System.out.println(chosen);
    }
    else {
      combination2Helper(chosen,                  remain.substring(1));        
      combination2Helper(chosen+remain.charAt(0), remain.substring(1));    
    }
  }
```

Comment: What did you learn from your execution trace?  Why is it not posted with your questions?  As given, your questions are too broad for SO.

Answer (score 1):

In the list version, you do not need to add `C` again to the list `remain` if you copy the list first:

```
  remain = new ArrayList<>(remain);
  String first = remain.remove(0);
```

In the string version, the statement `remain += C;` will be reached, but it has no real effect, because the value will never be used again. So it can be removed by optimization. The situation is similar to copying the list in the list version. Look at these statements:

```
  char C = remain.charAt(0);
  chosen += C;
  remain = remain.substring(1);
```

`remain` is an argument of the method. This will be assigned with the actual parameter, when the method is called. `remain` then behaves like a local variable of the method. When a new value is assigned to it inside the method, this will not change the variable passed by the caller (the reference to the string is passed by value).